# Android: Fast scrolling ListView weird behaviour of getPositionForSection

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I'm trying to implement a listview that has fast scrolling with header previews. It looks like it's almost working correct, but I'm encountering some weird, bug-like behaviour. When I scroll down without using the fast scroll bar, the fast scroll bar disappears, and reappears only almost at the end. So there seems to be a gap or something like that.
My ListView's ArrayAdapter implements SectionIndexer and it's methods `getSections()`, `getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex)` and `getSectionForPosition(int position)`. The getPositionForSection method is in my belief, the one causing trouble. When I log the value given by sectionIndex and I scroll down the list, this value exceeds the length of the actual sections (which is 20). This value comes from the SectionIndexer, not from myself. The [Android refererence](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html#getPositionForSection(int)) states:

> If the section's starting position is outside of the adapter bounds,
>   the position must be clipped to fall within the size of the adapter.

But when I clip the value to either 0 or section_size -1 (=19), the weird behaviour keeps appearing. Below is my ListView's ArrayAdapter implementing SectionIndexer. One note: the updateSections method is called from outside the adapter when the data changes in an AsyncTask. I hope someone knows what the problem is! Thanks in advance.

```
public class SoortArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Soort> implements SectionIndexer {
    List<Soort> data;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private ArrayList<String> sections;
    public SoortArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<Soort> data) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, data);
        this.data = data;
        sections = new ArrayList<>();
        alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    private void updateSections() {
        alphaIndexer.clear();
        sections = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            String s = data.get(i).getNaam().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(s)) {
                alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
                sections.add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(data.get(position).getNaam());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {

        return sections.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
        System.out.println(sectionIndex);
        if (sectionIndex >= sections.size()) {
            return 0;
        }
        System.out.println("position for section=" + sections.get(sectionIndex));
        return alphaIndexer.get(sections.get(sectionIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        String section = data.get(position).getNaam().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("section for position=" + section);
        return alphaIndexer.get(section);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I misread the documentation for the above stated methods getSectionForPosition() and getPositionForSection(), especially for getSectionForPosition(). This made getPositionForSection() act strangely. I corrected my implementation, so the final implementation of the two methods is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
        if (sectionIndex >= sections.size()) {
            return data.size() - 1;
        }

        if (sectionIndex < 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        return alphaIndexer.get(sections.get(sectionIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        String section = data.get(position).getNaam().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < sections.size(); i++) {
            if (section.equals(sections.get(i))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```